# Where to hunt for pigs in Far Cry 3?

Tags: far-cry-3

I want to craft equipment that requires pigs' skin. Yet I cannot find any pig on the map, only boars. Where to look for them?

Comment: Have you tried Rook Islands?

Comment: @deutschZuid, Rook Islands is the entire area of the game.

Comment: @agent86 Lol... thanks. Obviously I never played the game ;).

Comment: I can vaguely remember the map having the animals on them, and pigs were just hard to recognize, but once you had it, in that area there were tons of them (I used to hunt them with a car)

Answer (score 1):

I had the darndest time finding Pigs during my playthrough.  I found them somewhat randomly in areas that occasionally had boars.

This video seems to suggest a hunting spot east of Heron's Perch: